# How can I speed up or slow down old 3D games?

Tags: backwards-compatibility

I want to speed up or slow down some directx games for some test purposes. There are some tools or another methods to accomplish this?

Comment: Can provide more details of what you want to do. At first glance this sounds like it might be better off on the Game Development site - but if you not a developer I'd be reluctant to move it there.

Comment: I'm new here, but I don't think you'll get much help cheating here.

Comment: Every game has some sort of own "heartbeat" of its engine, so it would surprise me if there was such a tool to slow down any DX game. What is your real purpose behind this? Maybe we could offer an alternative.

Comment: @tenfour Such a technique would only get you owned in multiplayer, since no multiplayer game waits for frames to advance the state. I don't mind single player cheats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

http://www.asoftech.com/as/index.html

It isn't free, but really slow down the game. I've tested with desmume emulator + pokemon white rom, and the game speed really changed. I don't know if it really speed up, but slow it does. :)

Now, I know that is possible, I can try develop myself or search free alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

For some games, the single best way to cause artifical slowdowns is recording using FRAPS or equivalents. Since the encoding burden is mostly constant frame by frame, it more or less causes an uniform delay on the game.

Comment: Now, if you were a developer, you could try and attach on DX surfaces and get some kind of hook to add your own delaying to. How well this works depends on the game itself, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Cheat Engine. It has a *SpeedHack* feature. It slows or accelerate most games I used it with. I'm not sure about emulators, but if the game is compiled as an 'exe' there is an fairly high chance of success. Also, it **is free** and open-source.